# What am I missing? Void error

Tags: java

I am 15 year old boy which started to learn Java yesterday, I don't know anything at all, so today the teacher was coding so I wrote the same stuff he did, but then it shows me the following error : "Illegal type, "void" " .

Here the code.

[image]

I know it's a very stupid question but I started yesterday, as I said I don't know anything yet, I am just wondering what am I doing wrong and why doesn't the code work as the one the teacher did.

Thank you :)!

Comment: you need a public class

Comment: Is this code inside a class declaration?  eg `public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String[] argv) { } }`

Comment: I think you learn more if you find it out youreself

Answer (score 1):

In order to write a proper class, you need to wrap it in a class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your final curly brace for your method. Add one more curly brace to the end of your code. Also you wrote `if smallerNumber = scanner.nextInt()` instead of `int smallerNumber=scanner.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

From the image it looks like all you're missing is a `}` at the end of your file.